# Is creating complex STL Containers efficient?

Tags: c++, stl

I am going through some codes that create complex stl containers as below.

```
map<string, list<pair<string, set<complexclassX*>>>>
```

or like

```
map<string, list<pair<complexclassX*, set<complexclassY*>>>>
```

Here, map, list set, pair are all used for one object. Is it a good practice or can it be better designed ?

Comment: Hard to comment on the design without knowing what they are used for.

Comment: It can make things more complex, especially if the different class names are not significative.
I would try refactoring the code to put the "list" part of a the map into a proper wrapper class.

Comment: For instance, parsing files and searching and comparing tags in multiple files

Comment: This is begging for abstraction, but you probably don't want a `std::list`, as it's outperformed by `std::vector` a large majority of the time. And if those pointers are there because the class is big or something, I'd recommend normal objects.

Answer (score 2):

Specifically the contains you posted have no efficiency problem of being nested.
Containers that are moving elements like `vector` do. But with move constructors their cost is low, while not as low as pointers.
If you want to use containers like `vector`, wrapping the type with `unique_ptr` would have almost the same cost as pointers but you won't have to manage memory.

In any case, the container you posted looks complex. Splitting it to classes where each one contains one container will be more readable.